# Groovy - XmlNodePrinter prints blank file

Tags: xml, groovy

I am trying to print formatted xml to a file but my XmlNodePrinter just prints a blank file.  The xml object that I am passing in is populated correctly, I think.  I can print it using a StreamingMarkupBuilder but it is formatted all on a single line.  I am not sure why I cannot use the XmlNodePrinter.  Here's the relevant part of my code.

The goal of the code is to modify an xml configuration file.  I have to do a find/replace on a certain permission.

```
File file = new File("input.xml")
def root = new XmlSlurper().parse(file)

def admins = root.user.findAll {it.@role.text().equals("admin")}
admins.each { admin ->
  admin.permission.findAll { it.@type.text().equals("RoleManagement") 
  }.each {
    it.@type = "AdminRoleManagement"
  }
}

String filename = "output.xml"
new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(filename)).print(root)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `XmlNodePrinter` requires a `Node` rather than a `GPathResult`

`XmlSlurper.parse` returns `GPathResult`

So the obvious solution is to use `XmlParser` instead of `XmlSlurper`

Or, you can use `StreamingMarkupBuilder` and do:

```
def smb = new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind { mkp.yield root }
new File( 'output.xml' ).text = groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize( smb )
```